# XML Tag grouping in RTF template to calculate totals via nested table not giving formatted output. Extra row in the nested table

Tags: oracle, rtf, bi-publisher, excel-template, oracle-xml-publisher

My XML Tag generated is as follows-

```
<P_MONTH>01</P_MONTH>


-<G_1>

<DIVISION>CA Division</DIVISION>

<DISTRICT>CA District</DISTRICT>

<DEPARTMENT>Global Operations</DEPARTMENT>

<DEP_EMPL_COUNT>9</DEP_EMPL_COUNT>

</G_1>


-<G_1>

<DIVISION>CA Division</DIVISION>

<DISTRICT>CA District</DISTRICT>

<DEPARTMENT>Laboratory Services</DEPARTMENT>

<DEP_EMPL_COUNT>11</DEP_EMPL_COUNT>

</G_1>


-<G_1>

<DIVISION>CA Division</DIVISION>

<DISTRICT>CA District</DISTRICT>

<DEPARTMENT>Corporate</DEPARTMENT>

<DEP_EMPL_COUNT>3</DEP_EMPL_COUNT>

</G_1>


-<G_1>

<DIVISION>CA Division</DIVISION>

<DISTRICT>S District</DISTRICT>

<DEPARTMENT>Corporate Administration</DEPARTMENT>
<INTERNAL_ADDRESS_LINE>100-01-000-000-210-99802-000-000000-000000</INTERNAL_ADDRESS_LINE>

<DEP_EMPL_COUNT>6</DEP_EMPL_COUNT>
<SERVICE_LINE>000</SERVICE_LINE>

</G_1>


-<G_1>

<DIVISION>CA Division</DIVISION>

<DISTRICT>S District</DISTRICT>

<DEPARTMENT>Corporate Technology</DEPARTMENT>

<DEP_EMPL_COUNT>1</DEP_EMPL_COUNT>

</G_1>
```

When I am using these tag like below in the RTF template-

```
DIVISION                            DISTRICT                    DEPARTMENT                 COUNT
<?for-each:G_1?> <DIVISION>         <DISTRICT>                   <DEPARTMENT>             <COUNT> <?end for-each?>
```

This is giving an output like -

```
DIVISION              DISTRICT                          DEPARTMENT                      COUNT
CA Division           CA District                     Global Operations                  9
CA Division           CA District                     Laboratory Services                11
CA Division           CA District                     Corporate                          3
CA Division           S District                      Corporate Administration           6 
CA Division           S District                      Corporate Technology               1
```

But I want the grouping to be done in the output and the total calculated as per the grouping of the district and division.
I have used a nested table for that. somewhat like -

[image]

But the RTF template is giving me an extra row in the output even though the RTF template formatting is correct-
[image]
 what can i use to remove the extra row and perfect the formatting

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a space or new line under the nested table. Use backspace to remove it. Once you move the curser from the cell, you should see the extra space go away. Also make sure the line spacing is single spaced.

Comment: well.. i did check but there is no extra space or new line under the nested table....... not sure how to remove the blank row

Comment: Find a way to share the template and example XML with us.

Comment: ive shared my exact issue in the next question ive asked..... I am kind of close without using an embedded table. I read in the oracle documents that is not the preferred method...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Click in the whitespace below the table (below Division Total), and pressing on Ctrl + [. This will reduce the font size to smallest. That should reduce the visible space.